# Reading values inserted by trigger in a different table

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

I'm having the following issue: I have a trigger on a table A, whose purpose is to compute some values and insert them in a completely different table B.
The problem is that, somewhere in that logic, there is a loop that requires the values that would have been freshly inserted into table B.
I've noticed that SQL Server executes all the `INSERT` commands at once, after exiting the trigger.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTrade]
ON [dbo].[Blotter]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

/* compute @Variables */

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CompletelyUnrelatedTableWithoutTriggersOnIt]
VALUES @Variables
```

Is there any way of `COMMMIT`-ing that `INSERT` and being able to read those values while still in the trigger?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be very careful with how you are constructing your trigger. If you're using `INSERT...VALUES()` in a trigger, it's a good indication that you're assuming there will only ever be one record in the `INSERTED` table. Never make that assumption. Instead your logic should be `INSERT...SELECT <computed cols> FROM INSERTED`

Second, if you want to get out the values you just put in, you could use the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause but I'm not sure that's what you mean (it's not entirely clear what you want to do with the values) then you will have access to the final values that were inserted "while still in the trigger"

If that's *not* what you want, perhaps it would be better to encapsulate all this functionality into a proc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer.
Regarding your first point,I'm only inserting variables ie: INSERT...VALUES(@FirstVar,@SecondVar,...,@NthVar)
Basically,what I want is the following:
1.When new row inserted in table A
2.Run trigger that uses values from table A and table B and inserts a new row in table B
3.If some conditions are met, the trigger may have to insert 2 or more rows in table B. The values for the second row to be inserted in table B are in part determined by the first/previous rows that were inserted at step 2
I need to read those previously written values, and they're not there

Comment: I hope the previous explanation helps shed a bit more light on my issue

Comment: so if you insert three records into table A you only want to perform one insert into table B (or do you have a cursor in your trigger?) Either way, OUTPUT is probably your best bet then, it will allow you to use the values from your insert into B inside the trigger.

Comment: Thanks @M_M, I've sorted it by adding an extra column to the A table that tracks which row I'm working on. Strangely enough, updates are available right away, not after the trigger ended.

Comment: They would be available. You can read your own uncommitted transactions but by default others can't (unless you're using read uncommitted isolation level or with nolock) either way, glad you're sorted out.